# FB Marketing API - payment system blocking but the ad account is okay

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have an active Ad account, but in payment methods my view "We have detected unusual activity on your ad account, so we protect it from ad interruption. Your ads will be restarted and will use your current balance as soon as you verified you account".

Account status is not blocked, but ads can't be shown because I can't Fund my account because of this message.

Is it possible to catch this message via Marketing API?

Comment: Hmm. `account_status` on the ad account is `ACTIVE`?

Comment: And `disable_reason` is `NONE`?

Comment: @ceejayoz account_status = 1, disable_reason=0..